# Use Charles Proxy to monitor traffic from an android game

Tags: proxy

Can I use Charles Proxy to monitor traffic for an online android game like PUBG. If yes then what all information can I get from this? Can I use this to monitor the packets which are sent to the game server while playing the game and get the information like the ping I am getting while playing the game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Online games usually use UDP (and sometimes also raw TCP and/or HTTP(s)) traffic, but Charles is a web proxy that captures only HTTP and HTTPs traffic. Therefore you will only see a small part of the traffic.

The in-game ping usually bases on the UDP traffic, therefore using a pry will also not help you to get your ping time. AFAIK PUBG has a built-in ping time viewer that can be enabled in-game.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This explains a lot. Is there some way I can monitor the UDP traffic to get the ping time. I know PUBG has a built-in ping viewer but I want to save this data to do some analytics.

Comment: You can use Wireshark to see UDP traffic. There are apps that can record Wireshark pcap files on Android. However UDP is stateless, therefore you usually can not identify which received packet is a response to what sent package, hence can't calculate the ping. For that you need an understanding how the PUBG protocol works. Also keep in mind that redirecting/recording traffic can have an effect on what you are trying to measure (like the "observer effect" in physics).